# What is supposed to happen with the transpose flag for glUniformMatrix with non-square matrices?

Tags: opengl, matrix, glsl, shader, transpose

I encountered what seemed to me as strange behavior using glUniformMatrix4x3fv. Specifically when I give TRUE as for the transpose flag entire rows of my matrices are missing in my shader variable (and those that are there are therefor out of order).

For example. Say I have in my GLSL shader:

```
mat4x3 T[m];
```

Then in my C++ OpenGL call I want to send a matrix whose entries are (stored in row-major order):

```
T = 
  1 2 3
  4 5 6
  7 8 9 
  10 11 12
  101 102 103
  104 105 106
  107 108 109
  110 111 112
  101 102 103
  204 205 206
  207 208 209
  210 211 212
  ...
```

And I call

```
glUniformMatrix4x3fv(location,m,false,T);
```

Then I see in my shader that the each matrix comes out **correctly** as:

```
T[0] -> 
    1   4    7   10
    2   5    8   11
    3   6    9   12
T[1] -> 
  101 104  107  110
  102 105  108  111
  103 106  109  112
  ...
```

BUT, if I store my matrix on the C++ side as (again row-major order):

```
T = 
    1   4    7   10
    2   5    8   11
    3   6    9   12
  101 104  107  110
  102 105  108  111
  103 106  109  112
  201 204  207  210
  202 205  208  211
  203 206  209  212
  ...
```

And try to use the transpose flag as TRUE with:

```
glUniformMatrix4x3fv(location,m,true,T);
```

Then in my shader the matrices show up **incorrectly** as:

```
T[0] -> 
    1   4    7   10
    2   5    8   11
    3   6    9   12
T[1] -> 
  102 105  108  111
  103 106  109  112
  201 204  207  210
T[2] -> 
  203 206  209  212
  301 304  307  310
  302 305  308  311
  ...
```

Every 4th row of my data is missing.

Is there a sensible reason for this? I find nothing in the [spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec21.20061201.pdf) (s2.1 p82).

GL_VERSION: 2.1 NVIDIA-1.6.36
GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION: 1.20

Comment: *T* and *T[i]* represent arrays or they are a graphical representation of the matrices?

Comment: They are just graphical representations of the matrices.

Answer (score 1):

> Then in my C++ OpenGL call I want to send a matrix whose entries are (stored in row-major order):

That's not row-major order. That's column-major order.

Given the following 4x3 matrix:

```
1  4  7  10
2  5  8  11
3  6  9  12
```

This is what a C++ array of this data in column-major order would look like:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}
```

That's what your data is. Feel free to insert space wherever you want; it's entirely irrelevant.

This is what the same data in row-major order looks like:

```
{1, 4, 7, 10, 2, 5, 8, 11, 3, 6, 9, 12}
```

As to the specific issue you encountered with transposing your data for 4x3 matrices, it may simply be a driver bug.

Comment: What do you mean "That's not row-major order. That's column-major order." The data of my first C++ matrix above for row-major order: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ...}; and for my second matrix just as you write:  {1, 4, 7, 10, 2, 5, 8, 11, 3, 6, 9, 12, ...}

Comment: @mangledorf: I meant exactly what I said: your data is in column-major order. Column-major order means that the first X values in the array are the values for the first column, where X is the number of rows in the matrix. The columns are all contiguously laid out, hence the term "column **major**".

Comment: But how can you tell me how my data is ordered. I'm making the specific point of telling you that it is row-major order. If I just wrote the entries of the matrix alone there would be no one of knowing if it was column- or row-major ordered.

Comment: @mangledorf: Everything you've posted about your code and the behavior of your application says that your data is column major. The only contradictory information is your insistence that it _isn't_ column major. So either what you've posted about your code is misleading or you are mistaken about the ordering of your data. This isn't a hard thing to verify. Given a matrix on the CPU stored as an array of floats, what are the indices that store the translation component of the transform? If your answer is 9, 10, and 11, it's column major.

Comment: No, I think you're mistaken. Maybe you are confused because GLSL is storing the data column-major. If my first matrix T which is size m*4 by 3 (on the C++ side) was column-major then the T[9],T[10],T[11] would be 204,207,210. If it is row-major order like I keep saying then T[9],T[10],T[11] are indeed 10,11,12. If the second matrix T (on the C++ side) was column-major then T[9],T[10],T[11] would be 301,302,302. It is row-major order like I keep saying then T[9],T[10],T[11] are 6,9,12. For this second matrix the translation component is (using row-major order) at T[3],T[7],T[11] values 10,11,12

Comment: @mangledorf: Perhaps you should take a look at how [row-major and column-major are defined.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) Because your understanding of the order is incorrect.

Comment: I welcome your exact explanation of why you think I don't understand row-major versus column-major. The example on the wikipedia you cite is exactly the same as what I've written here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4033/discussion-between-mangledorf-and-nicol-bolas)

Comment: The whole row/coloumn thing is a mess. If you have a set of three axis you can have either x, y, z rows or x, y, z coloumns. Regardless, you can index the matrix either {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8} or {0, 3, 6, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8}. So which is which? Is putting the axes into the matrix row vs coloumn definitive, or reading the data out of the matrix definitive?

Comment: @StephenJones: [It's neither; they are two separate things.](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/18929/8240) Column-major means that the first X values of an array are a matrix column. Row-major means that it's a row. What the axes are is a different question. Canonical ordering means the axes are columns; the other ordering is transposed ordering. So you have row-major canonical, column-major canonical, row-major transposed, and column-major transposed. Canonical ordering means you multiply vectors on the right, and transposed ordering means you multiply them on the left.